# Three.js GLTFLoader cant load gltf files on my computer

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

I am new to using three.js, JavaScript, html, and CSS and I am working on loading a 3d model. I have a program that is working when I pull a gltf file online, ex:

```
loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/cartoon_lowpoly_small_city_free_pack/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) 
{console.log(gltf);
scene.add( gltf.scene );
}, undefined, function ( error ) {console.error( error );} );
```

But when I try and pull a gltf file of my computer it doesn't work, ex:

```
loader.load('C:\Models\scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) 
{console.log(gltf);
scene.add( gltf.scene );
}, undefined, function ( error ) {console.error( error );} );
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? I am using dreamweaver as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers cannot load files like images or models from local disk (unless you disable security restrictions). To get around this you must run a local server during development, see [how to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) in the three.js documentation.

Comment: I am currently using Servez to run it as its on the link that you posted, but even still after that it doesn't work.

Comment: The URL cannot be `C:\Models\scene.gltf`, it would need to be something like `http://localhost:8888/path/to/model.gltf` depending on the directory from which you're running the local server, and the port number. Files outside that directory cannot be served.